# Generate Where clause containing comparison between ICollection and List, without executing any query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to filter rows from table `Users` using Entity Framework. `Users` and `Roles` have a n-n relationship:

```
 public class Users 
{
    public Users()
    {
      Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
}

 public class Roles
    {

        public Roles()
        {
            Users = new HashSet<Users>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

AND:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Users)
            .WithMany(e => e.Roles)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserRoles")
            .MapLeftKey("RoleId")
            .MapRightKey("UserId"));
            ...............
}
```

I want to filter `Users` based on `UserName` and their `Roles`. The number of users is large, so I want to execute the query *only after* applying the conditions and pagination.

I want to find users that their name includes input's `UserName` (if is not null or empty), and they have all roles of input's `Roles` list.

What code should I use to achieve this?

```
public Users FilterUsers(UserSearchDto inputParam, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
{
      var skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
      var take = pageSize;
      int total = 0;

      var isNotUserNameFiltered = string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputParam.UserName);
      var isNotRolesFiltered = inputParam.Roles?.Count <= 0; //Roles type is List<string>

      var q = db.Users
                .Include("Roles")
                .AsQueryable();

      q = q.Where(user =>
                (isNotUserNameFiltered || user.UserName.Contains(inputParam.Item.UserName)) &&
                (isNotRolesFiltered // ||  // what should I write here?
                ));

      // get totalcount
      total = q.Count();

      // execute and get result from database
      var data = q.Select(user => new Users
                                  {
                                       Id = user.Id, 
                                       UserName = user.UserName,
                                       Roles = user.Roles.Select(role => role.DisplayName).ToList()
                                  })
                  .Distinct()
                  .OrderBy(u => u.Id)
                  .Skip(skip)
                  .Take(take)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what should I write here?

The standard way is to use `All` method:

```
inputParam.Roles.All(roleName => user.Roles.Any(role => role.Name == roleName))
```

(you might need to use `role.DisplayName` depending of what is in `inputParam.Roles`)

But in EF6 you will get better SQL translation if you count the matches and compare with the count of the desired set:

```
user.Roles.Count(role => inputParam.Roles.Contains(role.Name)) == inputParam.Roles.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use .Contains/Any/All/etc for simple-type collections in IQueryable.Where clause (roles.All(...) in code below)
Here is abstract code (based on your) with username/role filters:

```
var skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
var take = pageSize;
var query = db.Users
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include("Roles")
    .AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
{
    var username = inputParam.UserName.ToLower();
    query = query.Where(u => u.UserName.ToLower().Contains(username));
}

if (inputParam.Roles?.Count > 0)
{
    var roles = db.Roles
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(r => inputParam.Roles.Contains(r.Name))
        .Select(r => r.Id)
        .ToList();
    query = query.Where(u => roles.All(inputRole => u.Roles.Any(userRole => userRole.Id == inputRole)));
}

var total = query.Count();
var result = query
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take)
    .OrderBy(u => u.Id)
    .Select(...)
    .ToList();
```

- Lines 8-12 – prepare query to filter by username (only in case
  username not null and not empty)
- Lines 14-22 – prepare query to filter by roles
- Line 14 – get total number of filtered users
- Lines 25-30 – take only users for specific page and transform it to
  DTO

**Notes:**

1. Query not executed until you not called .AsEnumerable() or .ToList()
   methods.
2. I preloaded Role Ids because SQL Server should make a lot of comparisons and comparison between Ids (int) faster than comparison between Role.Name (string/nvarchar). Lines 19-23

Comment: User1 has Role 1,2 and 3. We want to find users that have roles 2,3 and 4. So we should not get User1 as result. But with any() -as you mentioned in answer- it will be return as result. We need to be sure that input Roles is subset of User Role

Comment: @Elnaz What if User2 has Roles = [2, 3, 4, 5] but inputParam.Roles = [2, 3, 4]? Do you need Users with exact Roles or Users who have at least these Roles?

Comment: at least these Roles. I have a multi-select drop-down In UI.

Comment: I edited answer above and made changes to the algorithm, please take a look. Also, I'm aware of performance of this kind of filters, but I do not see anything simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this;

```
(isNotRolesFiltered ||  user.Roles.All(r => inputParam.Roles.Contains(r))
```